# ASP.NET MVC Simple logon page, username & password match but getting unauthorized message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ado.net-entity-data-model

I'm creating an application for school that has to be done using the MVC pattern. To begin with, I am trying to get a simple register and logon page up and running as if I can store and retrieve in my DB then the rest of the application should be fairly straightforward. I am using my University's sql server for my DB and using the ADO.NET entity data model (for the first time).

I was using an online tutorial to help me and it all seemed to work well enough, but the trouble now is that when trying to log-on using details already in my table I get a 'Http 401.0 - Unauthorized' page.

I know that what I'm entering in the email & password box is matching what is being retrieved from the DB as I tested with labels and they all matched. I'm using ASP.NET 4.5.2 if that helps.

[image: Unauthorized page]

My table is simple-

```
Email (pk)(varchar) - For logon
Password (varchar) - For logon
First_Name (varchar)
```

My code is as follows;

UserLogon View -

```
public class UserLogon
{    
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

User Manager View -

```
public class UserManager
{
    private ac9555fEntities dre = new ac9555fEntities();
    public string GetUserPassword(string userEmail)
    {
        var user = from o in dre.UserTables where o.Email == userEmail  select o;
        if (user.ToList().Count > 0)
            return user.First().Password;
        else
            return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Account Controller -

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult LogOn()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/LogOn

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(UserLogon model, string returnUrl)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            UserManager userManager = new UserManager();
            string password = userManager.GetUserPassword(model.Email);


            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            {

                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user login or password provided is incorrect.");
            }

            if (password == model.Password)
            {

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, false);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Welcome", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
    }
```

Home Controller -

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {         
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Welcome()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

LogOn View -

```
@model WebApplication5.Models.ViewModels.UserLogon
....
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ....
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
    ....
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
    ....
    <input type="submit" value="Log On" />
}
```

I do apologize if I have included too much/not enough code, this is my first time using MVC/ADO.NET entity data model. From looking at other stuff on here and elsewhere on the web, I feel like there is an extra layer of authorization that isn't needed but any of the solutions I tried, failed to work. Can anyone spot where my code is flawed?

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Where are you getting that error?

Comment: In the browser, is that what you mean? @StephenMuecke

Comment: What line of code cause it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry to seem stupid, but how can I find exactly what line of code is causing the issue?

Comment: @StephenMuecke i've added a screenshot of the page that shows up, if that helps?

Comment: Just put a breakpoint in the `LogOn()` POST method and step through it and find out when it occurs.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ok, I done that and it takes me to the modernizer-2.6.2.js script, I don't understand, does that mean anything to you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138386/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-acostea).

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have added the system.web section of my web.config page to the bottom of my question.

Comment: Why are you building your own UserManager? That bypasses all known things about securely storing and comparing passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occurring because your `weg.config` file dos not specify to use Forms Authentication. Modify the `<system.web>` section to include

```
<system.web>
    ....
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="10" /> // adjust as required
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

There however a number of other issues with your code.

- You should never store passwords in the data base as plain text (they
  need to be hashed and salted)
- Your second `ModelState.AddModelError(..)` code should be identical
  to the the first (never reveal which of the two values is incorrect)
- Its not really clear what your trying to do with your `if(Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && ...` code, but once you authenticate
  the user, it should just be `if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl)) { return Redirect(returnUrl); } else { return RedirectToAction("Welcome", "Home"); }`

I recommend you work through the basic tutorials on [Security, Authentication and Authorization](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security) and use the built in features of MVC and Identity to handle all this correctly.